# Controlling order of commands using buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window, command

In Windows form I have `Button1`, `Button2` and `Button3`. These buttons represent a series of actions that should be carried out in a order from starting action to final action. So that normally I can handle this as follows.

```
Form1: Form
{

    Form_Load(Object sender, event Args e)
    {
        Button1.Enabled = true;
        Button2.Enabled = false;
        Button3.Enabled = false;
    }


    Button1_click(Object sender, event Args e)
    {
        //Actions
        Button2.Enabled = true;
        Button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    Button2_click(Object sender, event Args e)
    {
        //Actions
        Button3.Enabled = true;
        Button2.Enabled = false;
    }

    Button3_click(Object sender, e)
    {
        //Actions
        Button3.Enabled = false;
        Button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

In several places I'm doing it in this way. Is this the standard way?

**EDIT:**

And also in a simple situation like you should have clicked `button1` before clicking `button2`, the above approach is acceptable?

Comment: Make a List of buttons, add all buttons to the collection, make a method that sets all buttons 'Enabled' property to false, and sets a specific button (based on a reference or simply an index) Enabled to be true. Piece of cake. If you want to expand this, you might want to use Generics instead for handling some of this, but for this case, it's unnecessary.

Comment: "Standard" doesn't apply.  Depends on what you are doing and why you want to force that rigid behavior on your user.  What you are doing is fine.  You can refactor it as @BjarkeSøgaard has suggested, but it might not be worth the trouble.

Comment: I see no problem with your approach, unless you also need to allow the user to go back..

Comment: I agree with @DonBoitnott. There is no "Standard" way to do this kind of behavior. There are endless posibilities to end up with the same results. As an idea, I'd move the action codes to own methods, which I'd then call in place of `//Actions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what Bjarke said, I'm providing a code example.

```
Form1: Form
{
    List<Button> listButtons = new List<Button>();

    public void EnableButton(Button btnToEnable)
    {
        foreach(Button btn in listButtons)
        {
            //check button name.
            //if it is the button to enable, enable it, if not then disable it
            btn.Enabled = btn.Name == btnToEnable.Name;
        }
    }

    Form_Load(Object sender, event Args e)
    {
        listButtons.Add(Button1);
        listButtons.Add(Button2);
        listButtons.Add(Button3);

        EnableButton(Button1);

        //Button1.Enabled = true;
        //Button2.Enabled = false;
        //Button3.Enabled = false;
    }


    Button1_click(Object sender, event Args e)
    {
        EnableButton(Button2);
        //Actions
        //Button2.Enabled = true;
        //Button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    Button2_click(Object sender, event Args e)
    {
        EnableButton(Button3);
        //Actions
        //Button3.Enabled = true;
        //Button2.Enabled = false;
    }

    Button3_click(Object sender, e)
    {
        EnableButton(Button1);
        //Actions
        //Button3.Enabled = false;
        //Button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```